# Unity iOS RequestStoreReview more info

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I want ask my users to rate my Unity iOS app using the following code

```
Device.RequestStoreReview()
```

But this function returns true when the library is present and false otherwise. I want to know whether the user

1. Allready rated
2. Clicked "cancel" or clicked "not now"

So that I don't have to ask that to the user every single session

Comment: I would imagine that under the covers this function is calling [`SKStoreReviewController.requestReview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) - This function does not provide any feedback as to whether the user left a review or not.  This is by design. Also note that a call to this function may or may not result in a review request being shown to the user.  You should request a review at an appropriate time; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom UI with buttons to check if the user wants to review the app or not. If the user decides to give the review you can open the app store with `Application.OpenURL`. You can then save user action (reviewed, ask later, don't ask again) as a flag in PlayerPrefs. Use this flag in your app to decide when and how often ask the user for a review.

As far as I know there is no way to check if the user left the review or not but if they decide to go to app store, most will leave the review and even if they don't the app just won't ask them again. It is good enough for me.

This approach is also platform independent (as long as you can use `Application.OpenURL` you can forward your user to any app store/website for a review).

Comment: This is exactly the way I handle it in Android. I've made my own Rate plugin sort of say. But since iOS has native integration, I'd prefer to use their sdk. Just stupid that there are no callbacks as that would practically integrate perfectly in my own plugin

Comment: I am not exactly sure about this native approach (I have not used it) but I think they handle it for you. I mean calling this function won't show the dialog if the user already left the review. "requestReview() Tells StoreKit to ask the user to rate or review your app, if appropriate."

Comment: I think there are no callbacks as they don't want us reward users for leaving reviews